# Code::Blocks - How to show gutter/vertical right margin line in editor

Tags: codeblocks, margin, gutter

How to show the vertical right margin line (usually 80 characters) in the editor window in Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 6):

For the current Code::Blocks version (16.01):

1. Go to **Toolbar -> Settings -> Editor**
2. Under the list of categories (icons) on the left, select **Margins and Caret**
3. In the **Right margin** section, change **Right margin hint** to visible line
4. You can also change the color and column number
5. Click OK to save